# When [it is/was] necessary

Tags: adjective-phrases

I know that instead "where it is necessary" one could say "where necessary". Does it also work for past tense? For example

> I added a description in description field where it was empty

Can it be written as

> I added a description in description field where empty

Comment: in the description field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you added the description, the field's "emptiness" would have been in the past. So past tense is implied, even if you don't write it.
The use of "added" defines the tense.

Answer (score 0):

Your example sentence is a little awkward, but, that aside, the same omission can be used with all tenses.

> I filled in the blanks where necessary.
>   I am filling in the blanks where necessary.
>   I am going to fill in the blanks where necessary.

In addition to *where necessary*, we can also say *as necessary*.